# OAuth always failing registering existing users

Tags: github, oauth, sonarqube

I'm seeing some behavior out of the **SonarQube 5.4 OAuth** code that just doesn't make sense (one of those, this how could have never worked issues) so I know I'm missing something but I just don't see it.

I'm attempting to authenticate into a SonarQube 5.4 server with **sonar-auth-github-plugin, version 1.1.1**.

I can authenticate in using my gitlab credentials just fine the first time, however every attempt after that fails with the exception/error:

```
org.sonar.server.exceptions.BadRequestException: user.password_cant_be_changed_on_external_auth
        at org.sonar.server.user.UserUpdater.updateUserDto(UserUpdater.java:258) ~[sonar-server-5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.user.UserUpdater.update(UserUpdater.java:149) ~[sonar-server-5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.UserIdentityAuthenticator.register(UserIdentityAuthenticator.java:56) ~[sonar-server-5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.UserIdentityAuthenticator.authenticate(UserIdentityAuthenticator.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.4.jar:na]
```

Tracing through the server code (and watching the updates to the mysql DB), the error makes perfect sense...after the first attempt the logic checks the DB for a matching user, finds it, routes the request to **UserIdentityAuthenticator::registerExistingUser()**, who in turn calls **UserUpdater::update()** with the data coming info from the oauth user profile data.

The problem is when its sets the ExternalIdentity data (provider and user ID) it also sets UpdateUser's **externalIdentityChanged = true**, which causes

`UserUpdater::isNewExternalIdentityNotEqualsToSonaQube`

to incorrectly return false because this check:

```
"if (updateUser.isExternalIdentityChanged() && externalIdentity != null)"
```

which causes **UserUpdater::UpdateUserDto()** to mistakenly think its an update to a local account and attempt to update the encrypted password field.

I've looked for properties that I could set to somehow reroute the logic or prevent this incorrect flow but I've had no luck.

So I'm in the position of having to ask....how does this ever work for more than a single login attempt?  and more importantly what am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This issue seems to come from the usage of LDAP and GitHub Auth plugin (could you confirm that you've also LDAP installed ?). Because from what I see in the code, there's an incompatibility in SonarQube 5.4 to use the GitHub Auth plugin and the LDAP plugin.
Could you please try SonarQube 5.5 which should fix your issue ?

Comment: I confirmed that’s the issue (we are running with both the LDAP and GitHub Auth plugin), when I removed the LDAP plugin from the configuration things seem to work.  Unfortunately, I can’t upgrade to SonarQube 5.5 at this point because if I understand correctly that version requires MySQL 5.6 or higher and we are deploying to a Cloud Foundry environment, whose marketplace currently only supports MySQL 5.5.  We would prefer to be able to support both LDAP and OAuth authentication, is there anyway I could workaround or address the incompatibility between the two plugins?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I'll post an answer then ! Unfortunately there's no way to make GitHub Auth plugin working on SonarQube 5.4, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this bug, it allows to detect an incompatibility between SonarQube 5.4, the LDAP plugin and the GitHub Auth plugin.
The only solution is to upgrade to SonarQube 5.5, which has fixed this issue.

Note that I've created a JIRA ticket in order to document this bug : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SQAUTHGITH-10